# How to give MultiPartfile to Reader in Java?

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-boot

I am passing MultiPartFile as a parameter to my function and read with CSVFormat, but it gives me null pointer exception here is my code.

I want to read from file and assign that values to my objects.
My CSV file like this:

Sender account,Receiver Account,Amount,Date

123,654321,100,19-07-2018 12:13:00

```
public List<BankAccount> readCsv(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        List<BankAccount> bankAccountList = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");



        Reader in = new InputStreamReader(BankAccount.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(file.getOriginalFilename()));

        Iterable<CSVRecord> parser = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader("Sender account","Receiver Account","Amount","Date").parse(in);


            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
            BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount();
            String senderAccount = csvRecord.get("Sender account");
            String receiverAccount = csvRecord.get("Receiver account");
            float amount = Float.parseFloat(csvRecord.get("Amount"));
            ZonedDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(csvRecord.get("Date"), dtf)
                    .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Istanbul"));
            bankAccount.setFromId(senderAccount);
            bankAccount.setToId(receiverAccount);
            bankAccount.setDate(date);
            bankAccount.setBalance(amount);
            bankAccountList.add(bankAccount);
        }

        return bankAccountList;
    }
```

Comment: where does it throw the NPE? can you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: 2018-07-28 00:45:56.274  WARN 2960 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.lang.NullPointerException


I think it is here, it can not read file
     Reader in = new 
     InputStreamReader(BankAccount.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(file.getOriginalFilename()));

Comment: Is it way to give file itself instead of its name ?

Comment: `BankAccount.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream` looks for a resource bundled with your application (in the .jar or .war).  If the user submits a file, it’s very unlikely that your application will be bundled with a resource whose internal path exactly matches the submitted file.

Comment: Yes you are exactly right ! I have found the solution. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CSVParser parserr = CSVParser.parse(is, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII,
            CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader());
```

Okay I founded it. Thanks !

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for the help! You should mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 16):

Working on [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot), I wrote this fragment of code.

```
public void some(final MultipartFile file) {
  ...
  Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream());
  CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withSkipLines(1).build();
  ...
}
```

Library for read the [csv](/questions/tagged/csv):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
  <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
  <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way for reading multipartFile

```
  private static final CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();

  public static <T> List<T> readCsvFile(MultipartFile file, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(clazz).withHeader().withColumnReordering(true);
    ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(clazz).with(schema);
    return reader.<T>readValues(inputStream).readAll();
}
```

with jackson-dataformat-csv

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```